# Write 0b11001001 in decimal

Tags: decimal, bit

Problem:

> Write 0b11001001 in decimal.

I tried the following:

> 11001001<sub>2</sub> = 1 + 8 + 64 + 128 = 201

but the answer is –55. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: This isn't a programming question the way it's written. But probably what's happening is that the digits you gave are supposed to refer to a signed byte... The first bit is 1, which means "negative", and further, it means to invert the rest of the bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is *correct* providing that the *underlying data type* is **unsigned byte**.
If the type is a **signed byte**, then it is of range [-128..127]. You've got 201
which is *out of range* [0..127], so 201 should be interpreted as a *negative value*.
In order to find out a corresponging negative value you should convert your 
code into so called *complement representation*:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations

1. reverse each bit
2. add 1

   11001001 -> 00110110 (reversed) -> 00110111 (one added)

   0b00110111 is 1 + 2 + 4 + 16 + 32 = 55 decimal

So the answer for **signed byte** is -55

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is a homework problem or test question?  If a string of bits represents an integer, it can be interpreted as either signed (in which case the value can be positive, zero, or negative) or unsigned (in which case it's only positive or zero.)

In this instance, you provided the correct answer for an unsigned integer with an eight-bit word length, but the questioner was looking for the value of a signed integer.

Signed values are usually represented using a scheme called two's complement, described here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement

-55 is the value of that binary sequence interpreted as two's complement, assuming an eight-bit word length.

However, there are other schemes for encoding negative integers in binary such as one's complement, which provides a different result:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones'_complement

Two's complement is usually preferred because there is only one representation for zero, while one's complement provides a positive and negative zero representation.

Anyway, the question seems to rely on implicit, unstated assumptions.